# delete cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a excel table and I want to delete if three column have same data delete second and third. I can write 4. column which datas same or different but I cannot set first 1. 2. or 3. column data

=IF((AND(A1=B1;B1=C1));"Same";"Different")

```
a   b   c

a   b   b

a   a   a
```

to

```
a   b   c

a   b   b

a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this into a new module, but the macro will run on the Active Sheet:

```
 Sub DeleteCells()
 Dim intResponse, i As Integer

 i = 1

 intResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you want " & _
 "to delete the cells?", vbYesNo)

 If intResponse = vbYes Then
 Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" 'does it one by one going down in the first column while the cell is not empty


    If (Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2)) And (Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 3)) Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
    Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
    End If
    i = i + 1


 Loop

 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you but I dont know how can I use this method where can I paste it .s

Comment: Push Alt+F11, then https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/excel-visual-basic-for-applications/insert-vba-module.png    and then paste my code and push the play button at the top

Answer (score 1):

With a formula is possible but a little more tedious than VBA. For example in E1 copied across to G1 and then E1:G1 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:$C1,A1)<>3,A1,IF(COLUMN()=5,A1,""))
```

Then Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete Columns A:D.

Alternatively flag the rows where the three values are the same (say with `=COUNTIF(A1:C1,A1)` copied down to suit) then filter that column to select `3` and blank out the values in ColumnsB:C (other than the header row).